# WebStorm : When I want to debug my HTML file, the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, webstorm

I just brought WebStorm from JetBrains and I already have a problem and it may be a stupid one.

Basically, I just wrote a simple basic code of HTML and an empty JavaScript file named `main.js` and I just wanted to try the debug options to get the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <p id="num1">Test for num1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But a few seconds later, I got an error saying that it doesn't find `index.html` which is the name of my HTML file.

[image: The exact error that I got]

So I'm a newbie on this IDE that I found a little bit harder than Visual Studio Code. And I don't really know what to do...

I tried to recreate my project, verify the correct link on the configuration and the tutorials of JetBrains didn't help me too...

[image: Screen of my configuration]

Anyways, if you need any more pieces of information, files, or screenshots. Don't hesitate to ask me. :)

Comment: the error must be about `favicon.ico`, I believe. Please open Chrome Dev Tools console - can you see any errors there?

Comment: You right.. I don't have the ```index.html``` error anymore but :
```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :63342/favicon.ico:1```